# Observable distinctUntilChanged returns duplicates

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Setup: `RxSwift 4.2` `Swift 4.1` `Xcode 9.4.1`

I'm currently using `distinctUntilChanged` to get unique values.
But in my case it's only working for "sorted" values.

Like for example here:

```
func unique(source: Observable<Int>) -> Observable<Int> {
    return source.distinctUntilChanged()
}
```

Here is the corresponding test:

```
func testUnique() {
    let input = Observable.from([1,2,3,4,4,5,4])
    let expectation = [Recorded.next(0, 1),
                       Recorded.next(0, 2),
                       Recorded.next(0, 3),
                       Recorded.next(0, 4),
                       Recorded.next(0, 5),
                       Recorded.completed(0)]

    _ = Class().unique(source: input).subscribe(observer)

    XCTAssertEqual(observer.events, expectation)
}
```

And my test is failing with:

```
XCTAssertEqual failed: ("[next(1) @ 0, next(2) @ 0, next(3) @ 0, next(4) @ 0, next(5) @ 0, next(4) @ 0, completed @ 0]")
is not equal to ("[next(1) @ 0, next(2) @ 0, next(3) @ 0, next(4) @ 0, next(5) @ 0, completed @ 0]") -
```

So the last `4` is a duplicate.
Is this behavior expected or a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed expected behaviour, that is why operator is called '.distinct**UntilChanged**()'. What you apparently want is '.distinct()', but it is not available in basic 'RxSwift' framework, only in 'RxSwiftExt' framework - https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwiftExt#distinct

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behaviour. [distinctUntilChanged](http://rxmarbles.com/#distinctUntilChanged) is comparing with the previous value in the stream, in your case it should emit:

```
let expectation = [Recorded.next(0, 1),
                   Recorded.next(0, 2),
                   Recorded.next(0, 3),
                   Recorded.next(0, 4),
                   Recorded.next(0, 5),
                   Recorded.next(0, 4),
                   Recorded.completed(0)]
```

Think you can use `scan` to remember previous values and then just check if it needs to emit new value. Here's a quick solution using `scan`:

```
extension Observable where Element: Equatable {

    func unique() -> Observable<Element> {
        return scan([Element](), accumulator: { previousValues, nextValue in
            if !previousValues.contains(nextValue) {
                return previousValues + [nextValue]
            }
            return previousValues
        })
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .map { $0.last! }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made up a simple type specifiy answer myself.
It's basicly the RxSwiftExt `distinct` solution:

```
func unique(source: Observable<Int>) -> Observable<Int> {
    var cache = Set<Int>()

    return source.flatMap { element -> Observable<Int> in
        if cache.contains(element) {
            return Observable<Int>.empty()
        } else {
            cache.insert(element)
            return Observable<Int>.just(element)
        }
    }
}
```